# error when trying to add an interstitial Ad with ADMob

Tags: ios, admob

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GADInvalidInitializationException', reason: 'The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. Google AdMob publishers should follow instructions here: https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-ios-update-plist to include the AppMeasurement framework, set the -ObjC linker flag, and set GADApplicationIdentifier with a valid App ID. Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here: https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-ios-update-plist'

I've tried write a GADApplicationIdentifier in my plist but failed. I have the same error.

GADApplicationIdentifier string ca-app-pub-2246624909005244~xxxxxx

That is wrong. I have no idea now.

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: thanks.the first time to seek answer here..

Comment: @KnunLee Did you figure it out?

Comment: no..the offical way is not working...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ads SDK was initialized without an application ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58405905/ads-sdk-was-initialized-without-an-application-id)

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by declaring that my app was an Ad Manager. I added the following to my info.plist:

```
<key>GADIsAdManagerApp</key>
<true/>
```

Read more here: [Get Started Mobile Ads SDK](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/quick-start#update_your_infoplist)

Comment: i declared that my app was an ADmob.I have tried to add GADApplicationIdentifier in my info.plist..but it was not working..

Comment: Did you also just add the two lines mentioned above in the info.plist?